# Rest Assured - {"success":-1,"msg":"Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to use RestAssured to read the response from a GET request but I'm getting the following error in the logs:

`{"success":-1,"msg":"Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]"}`

Rest code:

```
    private Response setRestAssured(String uri) {
        RestAssured.baseURI = uri;

        Response res  =given ()
                .headers("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON, "Accept", ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get ("?ReqData=%7B%22latValue%22%3A39.7392358%2C%22longValue%22%3A-104.990251%2C%22productHash%22%3A7%2C%22clinicHash%22%3A3%2C%22radius%22%3A500%7D")
                .then()
//                .contentType("application/x-JavaScript")
                .extract().response();

        return res;
    }
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the request processing on the server side. Seems you are sending unexpected data and the server complains about.

Comment: you are sending a url encoded json in ReqData. There could be two probable causes. One could be that the server is not decoding the same. Second could be that the client may be url encoding your string again. Capture the http packet and see the req param that is sent to the server.